# How to install libssl-dev

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, software-installation

[image]

Could someone tell me where im going wrong?  I want to install openssl-devel for "Cern ROOT".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Did you try the suggested command `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? Or remove the package `debhelper` and reinstall the latest official version?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install a version of libssl-dev that requires a very old version of cmake. You might want to check if this is really the version of libssl-dev that you want or need. If it only builds with a cmake version that old, chances are it's a very old and unmaintained version. Especially with security software like libssl that's probably not a good idea.